# How to adjust position of FB.ui stream publish dialog box

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I m using FB.ui method in facebook to show stream publish box as follows:

```
function showfeed()
{
   var publish = {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    attachment: {
        name: 'XYZ',
        caption: 'caption here',
        description: ('description'),
        href: 'url',
        media: [{
            type: 'image',
            href: 'url',
            src: 'xyz.gif'
        }]
    },
    action_links: [{ text: 'XYZ', href: 'url' }]
    };  

   FB.ui(publish,null);
}
```

This works fine but my page is very long in height so when i click button to show this dialog it appears at center of page not at top so even dialog is display at center it's not display to me as i m at top. Is there any away to position dialog at top so any one can see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the code below to `<style>`. [got that from other forums) hope that helps

```
div.fb_dialog_advanced+div.fb_dialog_advanced {
top:50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`div.fb_dialog_advanced+div.fb_dialog_advanced { top:50px !important; }` does not work any longer. See this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz2me.jpg): [image: Old Solution]

But I've worked around the issue with jQuery. It's kinda hacky but it works:

```
function move_to_top( value )
{
    $(".fb_dialog").each(function(index) {
        if($(this).css("top")!='-10000px') {
            $(this).css("top", value + 'px' );
        }
    });
    setTimeout( ('move_to_top("'+value+'");'), 1250);
}

function send_request()
{
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'Press accept to see this request.', data: 'tracking information for the user'},
        function(response) {
            if(response!=null)
            {
                alert('You are boss')   
            }
    });
    $(".fbProfileBrowserResult").ready( function(){
        t = setTimeout ( ('move_to_top("'+50+'")'), 1250 );
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. Works perfectly for me. I noticed that you forgot to use the value parameter in the move_to_top function.  I think that $(this).css("top", '50px' ); need to be $(this).css("top", value+'px' ); There is also a small typo : $(this) instead of j(this)